# Finding the points on the graph of the function $\frac{1}{3}x^3 + x^2 - x - 1$ at which the slope is $-1$; $2$

Tags: calculus, functions

Please help me. Find the points on the graph of $\frac{1}{3}x^3 + x^2 - x - 1$ at which the slope is

(a) $-1$; (b) $2$.

I don't know where to begin.

Comment: $(a)$: Let $f(x)$ be the function of the graph. Then you have to solve the equation $f'(x)=-1$. $f'(x)$ is the derivative of $f(x)$.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Thank you guys and I'm so sorry if I didn't read the tutorial on how to typeset the figures! :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slope of the graph is equal to the derivative $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac13x^3+x^2-x-1\right)=x^2+2x-1$$ Now solve for (a) $$x^2+2x-1=-1 \iff x^2+2x=0 \iff x(x+2)=0$$ and for (b) $$x^2+2x-1=2 \iff x^2+2x-3=0 \iff (x-1)(x+3)=0$$

Comment: Thank you Stef!! I feel so stupid. :)

Comment: I'm sorry, what are the points again? Are the answers x(x+2) and (x-1)(x+3) ? Sorry for  this dumb question

Comment: @Amp You do not need to. Actually you asked for a hint where to start and I answered completely :(... Sorry

Comment: @Amp. No, you need to find the $x$'s that solve these equations. Then you will give the points as $(x,f(x))$. For example one solution of $x(x+2)=0$ is $x=0$. Then $f(0)=-1$ so one point with slope $-1$ is the point with coordinates $(x,y)=(0,f(0))=(0,-1)$. Do the same for the rest of the points.

Comment: Thank you. I think I got it. For a, the points are (0,-1) and ( 7/3, -2) and for b it's (-2/3,1) and (2,-3). Am I correct? :/

Comment: @Amp Actually reversed for the second point $(x=-2, f(-2)=7/3)$ but otherwise yes correct.

Comment: Lol i didn't notice. :) thank you so much!!!! you don't know how this made me happy

Comment: @Nice, I should have given only a hint though, not the answer! Next time you do it by yourself and you upload your solution ;)!!